# $n^\pi$ and $n^e$ for positive integer $n\ge2$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is it known if $n^\pi$ or $n^e$ are integer for some integer $n\ge 2$?

Gelfond - Schneider's theorem does not answer the question because both base and exponent should be algebraic and haven't found nothing about this in internet.

I don't expect a proof, it seems extremely difficult. Only references, if any.

Comment: There are either no or infinitely many solutions...

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Yes, if $n$ is a solution then $n^k$ either is for positive integer $k$.

Comment: @ajotatxe I am not seeing this. For all $n,q$; $n$ an integer at least 2 and $q$ positive rational, there is some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $n^a=q$. Suppose  that $n^a=q$ for some $a \in \{\pi, e\}$ and some integfer $n \ge 2$ and some positive rational $q$ that is not an integer. How would you find from this an integer $N$ s.t. $N^a$ is *integral*

Comment: If $p$ is a prime such that $p|n$ and $n^e = m$ does it imply that $p|m$?

Answer (score 3):

I think [Schanuel's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture) should imply that $n^e$ is never an integer. Here is the idea of how that could go:

Suppose $n^e = m$ then $e \log(n) = \log(m)$.

This would imply $\mathbb{Q}(1, \log(n), \log(m), e, n, m)$ has transcendence degree at most 2, violating the conjecture (assuming we rule out the case that $1$, $\log(n)$ and $\log(m)$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$, but that should be relatively easy)

I haven't thought enough about the $n^\pi$ case, but my guess is you could do something similar.

Of course Schanuel's conjecture is still open, but at least that gives you a place to start looking.